# Saving a JSON String in Java to a file

Tags: java, string, io

So I use GSON to convert my object to a String which is great with the following code:
However what I would like to be able to do is now save the String into a file(like .txt) and then open that text file on another computer and load in the JSON object.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String myObjectJson = gson.toJson(digitsSVM);
System.out.println(myObjectJson); // <--- this is working
```

My question is how do I save this String into a standard file and then open it before convert it back to my object?

```
MyObj obj = gson.fromJson(myObjectJson, MyObj.class); // converts it back to my object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start by taking a read through [Basic I/O](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/)

But the basic process would follow something along the lines of ...

```
// To write...
BufferedWriter bw = null;
try {
    bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("MyJson.txt")));
    bw.write(myObjectJson);
} finally {
    try {
        bw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}

// To Read
BufferedReader br = null;
try {
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileWriter(new File("MyJson.txt")));
    myObjectJson = br.readLine();
} finally {
    try {
        br.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Note, that these two operations will throw an `IOException` which I've not caught, as you need to deal with it accordingly to your requirements

Answer (score 2):

Files can be treated as Streams, so just use JsonReader and JsonWriter.  An example can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/gson-streaming-to-read-and-write-json/), and documentation [here](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming).